# Is it mandatory to use a leveling product on particle board when laying ceramic tile?

Tags: ceramic-tile

I pulled the carpet up in a 10 ft hallway to find particle board underneath. I reached my limit on funds thinking I bought everything I would need, but now I'm not sure what to do.

I have Ultraflex LFT so will it be okay to use that without a leveling product first?

Comment: are you sure it is particle board and not osb ?

Comment: If the floor is flat(does not need to be level) and very solid, no levelling should be needed.  Ceramic tile used to want ~ 1.5 inches of sub floor to prevent any bounce/movement of the floor.  Ceramic tile does not bend.

Comment: How about an image of this "particleboard"? People will often mistakenly describe OSB as "particleboard."

Comment: Tile should not be set on particle board _or_ OSB. In that light, the question is moot.

Comment: What were you expecting to find under your carpet? Did your original plan/budget include an underlayment of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

Floor flattening is rarely necessary for LFT thinset. LFT thinset typically collapses to a 1/4" bedding layer, allowing a lot of problem spots to be fixed without a flattening product. That said, it depends on your particular floor. If you've got gouges in the floor, then a product like "FeatherFinish" can be used, although in the case of particleboard it may be wise to tear up the particleboard.

Using thinset (your Ultraflex LFT) on an engineered wood product (like particleboard, OSB, or plywood) requires waterproof adhesive in the engineered wood product. If your subfloor is definitely particleboard, then it doesn't satisfy this waterproof adhesive requirement. Further, particleboard swells extremely with water, where this "dimensional instability" makes it inappropriate for tile also.

You need an appropriate underlayment for your tile. This is going to add another 3/8" minimum in height to your tile install. Tearing up the particleboard could potentially lower the height of your final install. You need to better document your subfloor.